# spring security oauth2 login using database

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I have created a REST service using spring and security with `oauth2` currently when I hit the url I get the access token and then using it I send my basic login credentials which is static in my file in the `spring_security.xml` file.
How can I provide user authentication using database?

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
<authentication-provider>
<user-service>
<user name="majid" password="majid" authorities="ROLE_APP" />
<user name="majid1" password="majid1" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
</user-service>
</authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide your custom implementation of AuthenticationProvider interface

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="authenticationProvider" 
     class="com.mycompany.security.MyDatabaseAuthenticationProvider"/>
```

Implementation would look sth. like this

```
public class MyDatabaseAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) {
        final String username = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
        final String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

        // perform your database stuff and return Authentication object

    }
}
```